# Find the probability of solutions of an equation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $x+y+z=20$. What is the probability that all the solutions are distinct? (No two variables have the same value). Assuming that the solutions are only positive integers or zero.

I have tried- $n(S)=\frac{22!}{2!20!}$ 
**EDIT**:$n(S)=231$. Now suppose we choose any two variables $x,y,z$, which can be done in ${3 \choose 2}$ ways. Now no. of ways of getting the same value in the two chosen variables-$10$. Now ${3 \choose 2}*10=30$. So probability will be: $1-\frac{30}{231}=\frac{67}{77}$. So where did I commit the mistake? 
Edit: Sorry, the question says that solution can be zero too.

Comment: What solutions have you found so far?

Comment: Let me update the question.

Comment: You may find non-distinct solutions and then subtract. The $x,y,z$ can't be equal all together, $3x\neq 20$, so you need just a case $(x=y)\neq z$ (up to permutations of $x,y,z$).

Comment: But how do I count it and then I'll have to double it for $x\neq y=z.$

Comment: If we are using **positive** integer solutions, presumably equally likely, the denominator is $\binom{19}{2}$.

Comment: The denominator or $n(S)$, as I calculated is 231. And I want the numerator.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the inconvenience. But zero is counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of partitions of $17$ into up to three parts is $33$ (see for example [A001399](https://oeis.org/A001399)),

so the number of partitions of $20$ into exactly three positive parts is $33$,

so the number of partitions of $23$ into exactly three distinct positive parts is $33$,

so the number of partitions of $20$ into exactly three distinct non-negative positive parts is $33$,

so the number of compositions of $20$ into exactly three distinct non-negative positive parts is $3!\times 33 = 198$,

so the probability all three non-negative parts are distinct is $\dfrac{198}{22\ \choose 2}=\dfrac67$.

The simple form of this result suggests there may be an alternative approach.

Comment: What do you mean by partitions?

Comment: I calculated like this- $n(S)=231$. Now suppose we choose any two variables $x,y,z$, which can be done in ${3 \choose 2}$ ways. Now no. of ways of getting the same value in the two chosen variables-$10$. Now ${3 \choose 2}*10=30$. So probability will be: $1-\frac{30}{231}=\frac{67}{77}$. So where did I commit the mistake?

Comment: [Wikipedia on partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: In your calculation, the pairs can individually take the values $0,1,\ldots,9,10$ i.e. $11$ possibilities, not $10$.  Multiply that by ${3 \choose 2}$ and subtract the result from  from $231$ to get $198$.

Comment: Ok so 10 was the mistake

Answer (score 3):

You have three distinct boxes, and want to count ways to put 20 indistinct balls into them. The total count of solutions is, as you have calculated:

$$\frac{22!}{2!20!} = 231$$

Now, to generate forbidden solutions you can choose 2 boxes, then put the same number of balls $n$ into each of them, and the remainder into the other. Since the number $n$ can vary from zero to ten, the ways to do this are:

$$\frac{3!}{2!1!}\times\sum_{n=0}^{10} 1 = 33$$

Noting that there's no way to fill three boxes all with the same number of balls (20 is not so divisible), we are done.

Assuming that each solution has equal probability of occurring, therefore the probability that no two terms in the solution are the same, is:

$$1-\frac{33}{231}=\frac{6}{7}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. (Fill up the spaces).